# Error while starting mysql for the first time.Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

I am very new to programming and i just installed MySql in my mac. This is the version - "mysql-5.7.18-macos10.12-x86_64". After installing, i went to the Terminal to start Mysql. below is the command i used.

Kalyans-MacBook-Air:bin kalyanallam$ pwd
/usr/local/mysql/bin
Kalyans-MacBook-Air:bin kalyanallam$ ./mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I saw some similar question asked by another user with the same error. Someone there mentioned to reinitialise the data directory. so, i did the below.

Kalyans-MacBook-Air:bin kalyanallam$ ./mysqld --initialize
mysqld: Can't create directory '/usr/local/mysql-5.7.18-macos10.12-x86_64/data/' (Errcode: 17 - File exists)
2017-05-26T15:22:21.770930Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-05-26T15:22:21.778006Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

What shall i do now to access mysql now ? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: when i tried to login to mysql using "./mysql -u root -p" command. I entered the default password generated while installing mysql.                              But i got the below error.  "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"  How do I rectify this error ?